# Find the Lipschitz constant

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions, differential, gradient-descent

The question:

Let $f(x) = ln(x + \sqrt{3 + x^2}) + \frac{1}{2}(x-2)^2$ with no restrictions on domain.


Determine the Lipschitz constant $L$ for the basic statement:
$$| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)| \leq L |x-y|$$

I calculated $$\nabla f(x) = \frac{1 + (x - 2)\sqrt{x^2 + 3}}{\sqrt{x^2+3}} $$

And I know that
$$| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)| = |\frac{1}{\sqrt{3 + x^2}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{3 + y^2}} + x - y|\leq L |x-y|$$

But I can't come up with any idea of how to determine $L$ (Lipschitz constant) using the basic statement.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Differentiate. ${}$

Comment: What element should I differentiate? I don't understand very well

Comment: Use the mean value theorem to show that a bound on $f''$ will work as a Lipschitz constant for $f'$. It is not a particularly simple expression, but it is straightforward to determine an upper bound. I get (but could easily have made a mistake) $f''(x) = 1- {x \over (x^2+3)^{3 \over 2}}$.

Comment: I've found that $0.87 \leq f''(x) \leq 1.13$. With this result, can I say that $L = 1.13$?

Comment: If those bounds are correct, then yes, ses my second comment.